# Apply media queries in a style attribute (not tag, but attribute)?

Tags: css, svg, media-queries, inline-styles

I'm experimenting with responsive SVG files, and really want to select the appropriate image independently from the HTML page.

I want to have a setup, where I can pass in an SVG to an **img** tag, without any further dependency. Then have the SVG rendered before it gets returned in order to display.

As far as I noticed, if I put a **style** tag into the SVG, then it gets evaluated after the page has loaded, and can access page's DOM elements only, not encapsulated "in-SVG-only" elements. The only way to evaluate styles before loading the page is to put CSS into a style attribute of the entire **svg** tag. And having media queries there would be awesome.

Does this make sense to you? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 6):

Inline `style` attributes don't support media queries.

Comment: :( That sounds frustrating.

Comment: What about "media" attribute. Is it applies only to "link" tag?

Comment: Hrrgh! I have to incorporate some javascript DOM whatever, which I really wanted to avoid.